# Python dictionary usage

Tags: python

I create python dictionary based on the parsed data:

```
user_details['city'] = None
if api_result.get('response')[1] and api_result.get('response')[1][0]:
    api_result_response = api_result.get('response')[1][0] # city details
    if api_result_response:
        user_details['city'] = int(api_result_response.get('cid'))
        city_name = api_result_response.get('name')
if user_details['city'] and city_name:
    # do something
```

So, I do a lot of verifications if passed data exists, if `user_details['city']` assigned etc. Is there any way to simplify that?

Answer (score 4):

Another key feature to dictionaries is the `dict.get(key, default)` function which allows you to get a default value if the key doesn't exist. This allows you to make the code less cluttered with `if` statements and also `try/except`.

The solution is often a balance between `if` and `try` statements and default values. If you are checking correctness of values, keep the `try/catch` statements as small as possible.

```
    response = api_result.get('response', None)
    if response:
        city_name = response.get('name', '')
        try:
            user_details['city'] = int( reponse.get('cid', 0) )
        except ValueError, e:
            pass # report that the 'cid' value was bogus
```

Comment: I think your answer would be better to include the numerical indexes as well as the string ones.

Comment: FWIW, PEP8 asks you to use `if response is not None:`

Comment: @WielandH., this way you will get an `AttributeError` on the next line, if response will happen to be `0`/`[]`/`False`/`()`

Answer (score 2):

You should just use `try`/`except` here:

```
try:
    response = api_result['response'][1][0]
    user_details['city'] = int(response['cid'])
    city_name = response['name']
except KeyError, IndexError:
    pass
else:
    # do something
```

The `else` on a `try`/`except` block is only executed if the `try` block ended normally, i.e. no exception was raised.

You may also want to catch 'ValueError' in case `int()` is passed an invalid value.

Comment: +1, but I'd note that you should be careful with this. If you call a function inside that block, it may raise a IndexError due to a bug, which will be hidden by this code.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a class that let me do this:

```
data = DataExtractor(api_result)
try:
    city = data.fetch('response', 1, 0, 'cid', int)
    city_name = data.fetch('response', 1, 0, 'city_name', str)
except DataExtractionError:
    print "Couldn't get the data!"
```

Then I'd just have to worry about checking the validity of incoming data in one place, DataExtractor. It will take care of verifying anything I throw at it, and will always throw the DataExtractionError if something doesn't line up. As Paul Martel points out, you should give the arguments of fetch to DataExtractionError so you can have a clear error message.

Another option to consider is using a json schema validator. Most of them can be used with objects that aren't actually JSON. Here is a link to PyPi which lists a few of them.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=json+schema&submit=search

The basic idea is that you tell it the structure of the data, and it can determine whether or not it actually fits. This can simplify your code because you once you've validated the data you can assume that the data's structure is correct and you don't have to do as much testing.

Comment: +1, and `DataExtractionError` should contain the arguments passed to data.fetch and the exception condition (missing value or wrong type) so you can print what when wrong in the except block.

Comment: @PaulMartel, excellent point!

Comment: @WinstonEwert, omg, what are all those arguments? How about going 1 step further and hiding them under the argumentless `DataExtractor.get_city_id()` and `DataExtractor.get_city_name()`?

Comment: @MishaAkovantsev, the argument specifies where in the data structure the piece of information you are interested lies. The op accesses `api_result['response'][1][0]['cid']` and I'm suggesting that he should pass all those keys to a function which can handle the logic of safely extracting in one place.

Comment: @MishaAkovantsev, the arguments tell it where the data lives. DataExtractor is not specific to a single extraction task, but can be reused for any data structure you find yourself with. So having a `get_city_id()` function doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @WinstonEwert, I got that, I just didn't thought of `DataExtractor` being **that** generic.